# Return duplicate data rows in a table

Tags: c#, datatable

I am new to C# (learned it yesterday), and I have a problem with the following code.

I have a data table and want to **print duplicate rows**, if there are any. This is my code:

```
DataTable myTable = myDataSet.Tables[0];

int row_count = myTable.Rows.Count;
bool duplicate_exist = false;
string message = "";

for (int i = 0; i < row_count; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < row_count; j++)
    {
        var array1 = fills.Rows[i].ItemArray;
        var array2 = fills.Rows[j].ItemArray;

        if (array1.SequenceEqual(array2))
        {
            duplicate_exist = true;
            message += myTable.Rows[i].ItemArray.Cast<string>().ToArray();
            message += "\n";
         }
     }

 }
```

The exception occurred at `array1.SequenceEqual(array2)`.

Any advice on how to fix the problem?

Comment: `got an exception at (array1.SequenceEqual(array2))` **Which exception?**

Comment: Probably not the right answer, but you can put constraints on your database so a table only contains unique entries.

Comment: How is the table being populated?

Comment: @AnimalStyle the table has 12 columns. Sorry what do you mean by how the table being populated?

Comment: @CommuSoft I am not going to get unique entires. the purpose here is to get duplicate row records. any advice?

Comment: Without knowing the exception you got it is very hard for us to help you.

Comment: Answer I4V's comment. Let us know the exception what Error message do you see in the output window. Put a try-catch block and inside catch use MessageBox.Show() to show the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the exception was at this `message += myTable.Rows[i].ItemArray.Cast<string>().ToArray();`

However, you should use `LINQ` to solve your problem:

```
//this comparer is used to compare 2 object[]
public class ArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<object[]> {
   public bool Equals(object[] x, object[] y) {
     return x.SequenceEqual(y);
   }
   public int GetHashCode(object[] obj){
     return GetHashCode();
   }
}
var dup = myTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.ItemArray, new ArrayComparer())
                                .Where(g=>g.Skip(1).Any())
                                .Select(g => g.First());
foreach(var d in dup){
  message += string.Join(", ", d.ItemArray.Cast<string>()) + "\n";
}
//E.g
//Input
1,2,3
2,3,4
3,4,5
1,2,3
2,3,4
//Output
1,2,3
2,3,4
```

If you want to print all the duplicated rows, just modify the query a little like this:

```
var dup = myTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.ItemArray, new ArrayComparer())
                                .Where(g=>g.Skip(1).Any())
                                .SelectMany(g=>g);
//Output
1,2,3
1,2,3
2,3,4
2,3,4
```